# How to stop Firebase from logging status updates when app is launched

Tags: ios, iphone, firebase

Whenever I launch the FireBase app, it logs the status of various Firebase features. Right now this is what is being logged:

```
Configuring the default app.

<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3200000 started

<FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see ...)

<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Successfully created Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy automatically. To disable the proxy, set the flag FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled to NO in the Info.plist

<FIRInstanceID/WARNING> FIRInstanceID AppDelegate proxy enabled, will swizzle app delegate remote notification handlers. To disable add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist and set it to NO

<FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
```

I looked through the pods and didn't find any print statements so how else would I go about stopping these from being logged overtime I run the app?

Comment: I agree with you. I'm also looking for a way to disable the messages.

Comment: Did you find a method?

Comment: There should definitely be a case for turning messages off. It does not matter how many of them is logged. I don't mind getting warnings and errors, but the initial messages are distracting, no doubt about it.

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can disable the debug logging with the flag `-FIRDebugDisabled`.

You can add it to your [scheme](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-scheme_editor/Articles/SchemeRun.html):

1. Select *Scheme* toolbar
2. *Edit Scheme*
3. Select *Run*
4. Click Arguments and add `-FIRDebugDisabled`

Comment: Ah I checked in with the engineers - those messages will be logged regardless. With the flag though, that's all you should see.

Comment: A `-noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` was renamed to `-FIRDebugDisabled`. Other steps are the same.

Comment: Not really good (this will likely not get added to code repositories etc and will thus cause different code depending on build method (think run/archive)). By default, release builds should have logs OFF... IMHO 

Comment: this has the awful side effect of turning of debug mode for firebase analytics

Answer (score 85):

Add `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)` before `FirebaseApp.configure()` to achieve the minimum amount of logging.

```
func setupFirebase() {
  FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
  FirebaseApp.configure()
}
```

Comment: This does the job!

Comment: Code has updated to FIRConfiguration.sharedInstance().setLoggerLevel(.min)

Comment: For anyone in objective-c:
`[[FIRConfiguration sharedInstance] setLoggerLevel:FIRLoggerLevelWarning]; [FIRApp configure];`

Comment: I had to move `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)` AFTER `FirebaseApp.configure()` to work correctly.

Answer (score 18):

By default, Firebase will log info, errors, and warnings.
So u can set the logger level for which ever u need.
If you set for .Error you wil get min log only when error accours.

setLoggerLevel before FirebaseApp.configure() as shown below

In Swift 2.3 and Firebase 4

```
 FirebaseConfiguration.sharedInstance().setLoggerLevel(.Error)
 FirebaseApp.configure()
```

In Swift 3 and Firebase 4

```
 FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
 FirebaseApp.configure()
```

Comment: How can I write this code in objective c can you please tell me thank you

Answer (score 17):

In my case to hide the extra chunk of console log from Firebase I did the following:

1. Navigate to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.
2. Under Arguments tab in the Environment Variables section add **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable**

[image]

- Just in case you will need that, just simply uncheck the box.
- Disabling **OS_ACTIVITY_MODE** sometimes will disable logs for all exceptions as well

---

**Edit 1**: As @jesus-adolfo-rodriguez said, this is related to Xcode. So, if you don’t want OSLog on the Xcode console, put OS_ACTIVITY_MODE Environment variable to “disable” in your scheme.

---

Edit 2:

```
FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(FirebaseLoggerLevel.min)
FirebaseApp.configure()
```

More details in the FIRConfiguration implementation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FIRConfiguration#-setloggerlevel)

---

**Edit 3: 2019**

According to this issue:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/2774#issuecomment-482780714

Adding **-FIRDebugDisabled** argument and cleaning the project did the trick.

**[The logging system in Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasecore/api/reference/Classes/FirebaseApp)**

> The logging system has two modes: default mode and debug mode. In
>   default mode, only logs with log level Notice, Warning and Error will
>   be sent to device. In debug mode, all logs will be sent to device. The
>   log levels that Firebase uses are consistent with the ASL log levels.
>
> Enable debug mode by passing the -FIRDebugEnabled argument to the
>   application. You can add this argument in the application’s Xcode
>   scheme. When debug mode is enabled via -FIRDebugEnabled, further
>   executions of the application will also be in debug mode. In order to
>   return to default mode, you must explicitly disable the debug mode
>   with the application argument **-FIRDebugDisabled**.
>
> It is also possible to change the default logging level in code by
>   calling setLoggerLevel: on the FIRConfiguration interface.

Comment: this has nothing to do with firebase

Comment: and will hide your analytics if you want them to be shown -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled

Comment: This disabled all the logs for me. As you said in the last point.

Comment: It helped me to reduce messages from Firebase which were logged notwithstanding `setLoggerLevel(.min)` and `-FIRDebugDisabled`. Great answer!

Comment: Stop telling people to disable all logging.

Answer (score 8):

Swift 4 Firebase 4.10

Set logger level in your AppDelegate.swift

```
FirebaseConfiguration().setLoggerLevel(FirebaseLoggerLevel.min)
```

Here is full code:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    FirebaseConfiguration().setLoggerLevel(FirebaseLoggerLevel.min)
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    return true
}
```

Comment: As of Oct 2020, this is the only answer that got rid of the Firebase logs, but left my own logging alone. Helps for analyzing what's happening on startup of your app.

Answer (score 7):

```
FIRConfiguration.sharedInstance().setLoggerLevel(.min)
FIRApp.configure()
```

In Swift 4

Comment: `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)` in FB 5.14

Answer (score 4):

By default Firebase Analytics will only log 4 INFO lines in production + errors/warnings. That should be very little output if things work correctly. Adding -noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled will only disable DEBUG level logs and ERROR/WARN are always logged. If you see any warnings or errors you probably need to do something to resolve the cause. Some things will likely not work correctly if warnings/errors are logged. App that is correctly setup should not log errors/warnings.

Messages tagged with FIRInstanceID/* are logged by Firebase Notification and errors/warnings are always logged.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is a big and a very important confusion going on.

By using `-FIRDebugDisabled` it will **disable debug mode** which then your [measurements will be affected during testing and development](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview#enabling_debug_mode).

Currently there is [no way](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5704#issuecomment-678449276) to enable debug mode and disable logs at the same time. So the `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)` will work basically on not debug mode only.

As workaround you can use `-noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` which is only for [Xcode console logging](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/5124#issuecomment-601174106), this one **does not disable** your debug mode.

Answer (score 3):

As djabi said, you cannot disable those logs if they are INFO, WARNING or ERROR.

I want to add to Nitin Gohel's answer since I can't comment: The flag **FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled** is not for disabling logs. If you turn it off, you will lose the auto **campaign** tracking and you will need to add the methods from FIRAnalytics(AppDelegate) to handle URL and user activity yourself.

Answer (score 3):

To add to Alex' answer, from https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client

`FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled` is for swizzling your app delegate 's methods

> The FCM API performs method swizzling in two key areas: mapping your APNs token to the FCM registration token and capturing analytics data during downstream message callback handling. Developers who prefer not to use swizzling can disable it by adding the flag **FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled** in the app’s Info.plist file and setting it to NO (boolean value). Relevant areas of the guides provide code examples, both with and without method swizzling enabled.

Answer (score 2):

If you want the clean and necessary logs in console, just set your scheme like this. Open the "Edit Scheme" and select "Arguments".

- -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled  (don't forget "-")
- OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

[image]

Comment: I would not recommend this. OS_ACTIVITY_LOG = disable will kill Apple's universal logging which means that any logging you do want will also disappear.