# How to disable Firebase/Core debug messages in iOS

Tags: ios, logging, firebase

I get several debug messages from Firebase - quite chatty:

```
2016-10-20 22:18:33.576 Sitch[1190] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed
```

I don't see any way to quiet them. FIRAnalytics only shows INFO and more severe but Firebase/Core seems to have debug enabled by default?

This is the cocoapods build - from podfile.lock:

```
FirebaseCore (3.4.3):
    GoogleInterchangeUtilities (~> 1.2)
    GoogleUtilities (~> 1.2)
```

Comment: you might wanna see this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311089/how-to-stop-firebase-from-logging-status-updates-when-app-is-launched

Answer (score 12):

You can disable the debug logging with the flag -FIRDebugDisabled.

Below are the steps to set this flag.

- Select Edit schema.
- Select Run.
- Select Arguments and add -FIRDebugDisabled.

Comment: This is the fix. @Jalakoo's fix will also probably work, but this is simpler.

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me:

1. Scheme: Run: Arguments: Remove -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled
2. Scheme: Run: Arguments: Remove -FIRDebugEnabled
3. Added `FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)`(probably not needed)
4. Deleted App
5. Delete Derived Data
6. Clean, Build & Run again

Offending arguments:
[image: SchemeRunArguments]

To re-enable, see [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview)

Answer (score -1):

You can disable the debug message for Firebase and other with the flag `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` with a value `disable`

You have to add it on your scheme run mode :

1 - Select your scheme on Xcode toolbar

2 - Edit scheme

3 - Add this key and value on `Environment Variables` section

4 - close your scheme and launch your app

Comment: This will silence much more than just GTM debug messages?