# How do I undo `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`?

Tags: ios, firebase-analytics

I just added `FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` as a launch argument as was suggested in several places:

1. The Xcode console:

   ```
   6.5.0 - [Firebase/Analytics][I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see [https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/])
   ```
2. The [Get Started with Google Analytics for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start) guide:

   > [image]
3. Etc.

Once I enabled it, I started seeing output such as:

```
Event is not subject to real-time event count daily limit. Marking an event as real-time. Event name, parameters: session_start (_s), {
    firebase_debug (_dbg) = 1;
    firebase_event_origin (_o) = auto;
    ga_realtime (_r) = 1;
    session_id (_sid) = 123;
    session_number (_sno) = 2;
}
```

Now that I know that events are being output properly, I want to disable this as it is spamming the console. However, none of those resources mentioned above talk about how to disable it.

How do I disable it?

I tried removing the launch argument, but the logs still appear.

---

Note that this is not a duplicate of these similar questions:

- [How to stop Firebase from logging status updates when app is launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311089/how-to-stop-firebase-from-logging-status-updates-when-app-is-launched) -- OP never enabled `FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` and is asking about how to disable the message telling them to enable `FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` (among others).
- [Completely disable Firebase/Analytics to stop console spam on app startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419076/completely-disable-firebase-analytics-to-stop-console-spam-on-app-startup/44438819) -- same as above.

Answer (score 15):

[Many places](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311309/35690) will tell you to add the launch argument `-FIRDebugDisabled` but because I didn't have it prior to enabling `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`, that seems odd.

It took a while to find, but the page on [DebugView](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7201382?hl=en&utm_id=ad&authuser=0) has some key information:

> To enable Analytics Debug mode on your development device, specify the following command line argument in Xcode :
>
> `-FIRDebugEnabled`
>
> **This behavior persists** until you explicitly disable Debug mode by specifying the following command line argument:
>
> `-FIRDebugDisabled`

The key here is that the "behavior persists." It appears that `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled` is behaving the exact same way in that it persists: you only need to run it once.

Thus to get back to the state you were in before running with `-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`:

1. Run the app once with the `-FIRDebugDisabled` launch argument.
2. Remove the launch argument.

Comment: Doesn't it work if you simply delete and reinstall the app?

Comment: @lulian Onfrei no it won't. That's the problem here. You have to run it again with the disabled argument on.
this is why I love XCode and Apple development.

Comment: it's documented here https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview

Comment: For Firebase v8.8.0 I had to set "-noFIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled" flag to turn off debug logs.

Comment: Super-helpful; I would never have found this documentation on my own.

Answer (score 0):

The FirebaseAnalytics framework is using [application defaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) to persist the setting. This means you can use the `defaults` command in the terminal to query or change the persisted setting without messing with launch arguments.

```
# turn it on
defaults write <bundle_identifier> "/google/measurement/debug_mode" 1

# turn it off
defaults write <bundle_identifier> "/google/measurement/debug_mode" 0

# read the current value
defaults read <bundle_identifier> "/google/measurement/debug_mode"
```

Tested with a MacOS application, but should also apply to iOS.