# Android release signed APK : Remove Firebase Analytics logs from output logcat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I created final version of my app's signed apk using android studio with minifyEnabled and shrinkResources true. After installing APK, app logs are gone and correctly not seeing anything related to app source in logcat.

But I am still seeing Firebase analytics logs which I want to remove. e.g. It shows puzzle being launched, ad being served, puzzle solved (whichever FA events I have added).

How do I achieve this ? In debug mode, I want to see FA logs, in release build/apk, want to remove all FA logs.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not the answer you want to hear, but here it is: **you can't disable logs in Firebase Analytics for Android.** You can do that on [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44419076/completely-disable-firebase-analytics-to-stop-console-spam-on-app-startup/44438819), but for Android there is no simple solution.

I'm not saying that is a good thing and I understand willingness to disable it, but it shouldn't be a security issue, if that's what you have in mind. Apps can't access logs of other apps (unless we are talking about really old Android versions), so the only way to see those logs would be to have access to physical device. And then probably Firebase logs - which should not contain sensitive data in the first place - are probably not your biggest problem.