# Avoid Firebase / BoringSSL Console Logs on iOS

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, boringssl

After installing Firebase (Cloud Firestore), I usually get tons of console logs, usually belonging to BoringSSL, such as this:

> 2018-08-27 13:49:03.747112+0100 VM[25611:371248] [BoringSSL] boringssl_session_errorlog(224) [C2.1:2][0x7f9570c142d0] [boringssl_session_read] SSL_ERROR_SSL(1): operation failed within the library

Is there a way to avoid logs from these (or any) external frameworks?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311089 ?

Answer (score 0):

Though the link to the relevant thread is correct, the top vote was given does not solve this problem with the lower dependency libraries.

To silence BoringSSL use

> OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

Steps

1. Navigate to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme.
2. Open the Arguments tab
3. Environment Variables section add OS_ACTIVITY_MODE = disable

[image: Scheme Editing]

Comment: For me that silenced everything including NSLog

Comment: @PDG try that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71865625/1837959

Comment: Thanks for this, it worked. If there are any side effects I notice I will post here.