# Firebase Analytics (iOS): How to deactivate the logging of events when running an app in the Xcode simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, logging, firebase-analytics

I have been spending some time now, trying to figure out, how to deactivate the logging of events in Firebase Analytics for iOS when running an app in the Xcode simulator.

Currently I have set Firebase up as described in Googles documentation. The issue is that Firebase Analytics seems to log events even when I run my app on Simulator/test device from Xcode. This messes with the statistics that I would see in the Firebase console.

**Can anyone help me out with information on how to prevent this behavior?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Conditional compilation? You know whether you're on the Simulator and/or in a Debug configuration, so if you don't want to do something then, don't do it then.

Comment: Hi @matt, so what you refer to is configuring Firebase Analytics conditionally with "#if DEBUG"?

Comment: I certain refer to using `#if`. What the condition should be is up to you.

Comment: Does this help ? 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37311309

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is what I ended up using:

```
func isRunningLive() -> Bool {
    #if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    return false
    #else
    let isRunningTestFlightBeta  = (Bundle.main.appStoreReceiptURL?.lastPathComponent == "sandboxReceipt")
    let hasEmbeddedMobileProvision = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "embedded", ofType: "mobileprovision") != nil
    if (isRunningTestFlightBeta || hasEmbeddedMobileProvision) {
        return false
    } else {
        return true
    }
    #endif
}
if isRunningLive() {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true)
} else {
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    Analytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false)
}
```