# How to stop firebase status logs in console screen (disable)

Tags: java, firebase

I am using java here.

1. I have referred this [How to stop Firebase from logging status updates when app is launched](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37311089/how-to-stop-firebase-from-logging-status-updates-when-app-is-launched)
   and followed adding  arguments `-FIRDebugDisabled` still couldn't solve the issue
2. Then I follwed this looks like it is for ios, Coudnt find  FirebaseConfiguration class.
   So I stuck

   ```
   func setupFirebase() {
      FirebaseConfiguration.shared.setLoggerLevel(.min)
      FirebaseApp.configure()
   }
   ```
3. `OS_ACTIVITY_MODE` I have disabled in environment still I find logging in console when i add the data to firestore.

What Actually I need:
I don't want to log firebase connection details in console . When I tried to communicate with database.